# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2995,) (8392,) ()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

This is my code:

```
check =['met ballen', 'jonge man','enthousiaste jongens','enthousiaste meisjes','enthousiaste jongen','dan ben jij onze man',
       'enthousiaste meid','enthousiaste meiden']
data1["Zoekterm_new"] = np.where(data1['Zoekterm'].str.contains(f"{'|'.join(check)}"), data['Zoekterm'], np.NaN)
```

When ik run this is give me the follow error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2995,) (8392,) ()
```

My dataframe has the follow columns:

```
Source.Name                 object
Mogelijke_discriminatie    float64
Zoekterm                    object
dtype: object
```

I turnd " Mogelijke_discriminatie " to an integer
with

```
data1.Mogelijke_discriminatie.astype(int)
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong

Comment: should not it be `data1['Zoekterm'], np.NaN)` ???

Comment: @Pygirl Thanks i really did not see this stupid mistake